# How to configure View Project-Level Information on Service Account?

Tags: tfs, permissions, ms-release-management

I'm attempting to use Release Management vNext in TFS 2015 Update 2 RC2, however whenever I try to deploy to an environment, I get the error:

> TF50309: The following account does not have sufficient permissions to complete the operation: [DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Service Accounts.  The following permissions are required to complete the operation: View Project-Level Information.

I've looked everywhere in the settings, and cannot seem to find a way to configure the [DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Service Accounts group with this permission, the closest it comes is "View Collection-Level information".

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If you have project level security permission, you can check user has 'View project-level information' permission. And check user is member of which groups and that groups have 'View project-level information' permission set.

Answer (score 0):

`view project-level` permission is **the permission of project-level**. Just the same as `View Collection-Level` permission for project collection-level.

If you want to give a user or group the view-project level permission. Please follow the steps below to set this permission:

- By GUI [Give "View project-level information" permission to User in
  Team Foundation Server](http://www.opshub.com/ohrel/Resources/TFS/permissions.php?page=viewprojectlevelpermission)
- By Command: `Tfs security /a+`  details you can refer from
  [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vs/alm/tfs/administer/command-line/tfssecurity-cmd)

However this may solve your issue: Adding your build account on the environment machine in the following group

[image]

Comment: As you might notice from the link you've given, the Project Collection Service Accounts group does not show up on the list of groups that can access the project.  Nor does any of the TFS admin/service accounts, and there seems to be no way to add them.

Comment: Then try to use the tfs command as above. For example:  `TFSSecurity.exe /a+  (namespace) GENERIC_READ n:[DefaultCollection]\Project Collection Service Accounts ALLOW /collection: http://TfsServer:8080/tfs/defaultcollection`

Comment: Even though I double this is not the permission error. Did you try to add your build account which on the environment machine in the  group(Project Collection Build Administrators and Project Collection Build Service Accounts)